# Reverse Bits Algorithm

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation, reverse

This is a very obvious and simple question that I am unfortunately having some trouble with. Reversing the bits in a given integer (not inverting/flipping the bits) making MSB to LSB and MSB-1 to LSB+1 and so on. In my mind, the way I think of doing this is to store the last bit of the input into an output variable and right shift that variable by 1 each time then left shift the input by 1 and repeat the process. Here is the function I have written so far to do this:

```
unsigned int oldRev(unsigned int input){
    unsigned int output = 0;    

    for(int i=0; i<((sizeof(int)*8)-1); i++){
        output |= input&1;
        output <<= 1;
        input >>= 1;
    }    

    return output;    

}
```

The issue arises when I try to do oldRev(2147483648) where only the most significant bit is 1 in the input. The output should be just 1 but I get 0. Why does this happen? I have been trying to figure out the issue with my logic but have been unsuccessful thus far. I have seen the various methods of doing this online but still want to know what I am doing wrong.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: for (unsigned .....?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to switch the order of two operations:

```
    output <<= 1;
    output |= input&1;
```

To understand why, stare at the existing code and pontificate the fact that it will always wind up producing an `output` whose last bit will always be 0. Because the last thing that ever will be done to `output`, always, no matter how big your `int` is, would be the left shift operation. Which would always leave `output`'s last bit as 0. Which is obviously wrong.

Also, since there are `sizeof(int)*8` bits in an `int`, the loop has to obviously iterate `sizeof(int)*8` times, to process that # of bits, but:

```
for(int i=0; i<((sizeof(int)*8)-1); i++){
```

This iterates `sizeof(int)*8-1` times. One less than the number required. This should be:

```
for(int i=0; i<sizeof(int)*8; i++){
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I understand the issue completely now